# How to destroy template instance?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a game template rendered by iron router (when you go into the game from default page).
When the game finished, I want the player to be routed to default page and the current game template instance to be removed.

For this purpose I use a hook on removed event for game collection. Which allows other players to be automatically redirected to default page when game ends:

```
Tempalte.game.rendered = function () {
  var self = this;
  var gameId;
  //some code here
  var game = Games.find({name: Session.get('gameName')});    
  game.observeChanges({
        added: function(id, fields) {
            gameId = id;
        },
        removed: function(id) {
            if (gameId === id) { Router.go('/');
               alert("Game finished");}
        }
    });
}
```

When I finish the game and create new one with the same name. The alert called twice.
One more finish/create => Three alerts.
It looks like the game template instance still remains somewhere in the background and monitors changes in Games collection.

So the question is how to properly remove the template instance when going to default page?
Tried Blaze.remove(self) not working because the game template wasn't rendered with Blaze.render().
In the router I don't know how to get the handle for the template instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the template instance still being there that is causing the alerts to stack up, it's your `observeChanges` cursor never being stopped.

You need to save a reference to it when you declare the cursor in the `rendered` callback to stop the observation when the template instance is `destroyed`.

```
Template.game.rendered=function(){
  // ...
  this.observeCursor=game.observeChanges(...);
};

Template.game.destroyed=function(){
  this.observeCursor.stop();
};
```